# (G)LMM for temporally clustered, autocorrelated data

Tags: mixed-model, autocorrelation, ordinal-data, glmm

I have data from a randomised trial structured according to the image below (Rand = Randomisation, EoS = End of Study), which illustrates fictitious data from two participants. The general goal is to compare change over time in Y between group A and B.

Multiple measurements of Y are made for each subject on 3 occasions over a comparatively short timeframe t (the number of measurements in each subject and occasion is itself random and roughly between 1 and 10). The temporal distance between the 3 occasions is relatively large in comparison, resulting in a very uneven temporal spacing of measurements. Also, a subject's measurements within a given occasion are likely to have some (possibly a strong) degree of autocorrelation (probably a simple AR(1) correlation will be sufficient to model this). I do not expect there to be relevant autocorrelation between the 3 measurement periods.

Y values may be either on a metric, an ordinal, or a binary scale (since multiple variables of different scales are derived from the samples). A separate model should be fitted for each of these variables.

My expected overall N is on the order of 100 and there is a small number of subject-level baseline covariates (like sex, age) which should be taken into account.

My questions are:

1. What would be an appropriate modeling approach to investigate the group difference (A vs. B) in change in Y over time when measurements within the 3 measurement occasions can **not** be aggregated to one value per occasion (e.g. mean, median), i.e. if the individual measurements are to be used? I was thinking of a (G)LMM with (besides the fixed effects) a random subject intercept and additionally an AR(1) autocorrelation structure within (but not across) measurement occasions, but I'm not sure if this is even possible especially for an ordinal (proportional odds) GLMM? Or will the autocorrelation not affect effect estimates & confidence intervals in a relevant manner and can be more or less ignored?
2. How could this be estimated in either R or SAS (must be one of those two, preferably R)? Especially the "autocorrelation + ordinal outcome" case is giving me some headaches here, I couldn't seem to find any good solution but that may be due to lack of familiarity with relevant packages.

[image: Data structure]

Comment: *"Also, a subject's measurements within a given occasion are likely to have some (possibly a strong) degree of autocorrelation (probably a simple AR(1) correlation will be sufficient to model this). I do not expect there to be relevant autocorrelation between the 3 measurement periods."*. How long does each occasion $t$ last ? Are you sure you need a within-occasion AR(1) process ? Differences between subjects will be handled by the random intercepts.

Comment: t is about a week. No indeed I'm not sure whether AR(1) or another form of autocorrelation structure is even needed; I was wondering because the presence of autocorrelation violates the assumption of independence of measurements within a subject, but I'm not sure whether that would even have any appreciable impact on the results